# choosing between two xml files at the onCreate(), possible?

Tags: android, xml

> i want to choose between two xml files when the application starts i.e in onCreate().

For example say i am reading the battery status when the app opens, if its less then some level i should display a warning message or the start activity of the app. Is this feasible???? If there is any way, can i get some help????

> my code

```
isSDCard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(isSDCard)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,SDcard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            //setContentView(R.layout.missing_sd);
        }
        else{

            //Intent intent = new Intent(this,ImageSelection.class);    
            //startActivity(intent);
        //  finish();
            setContentView(R.layout.image_menu);
        }
  }
```

> my SDcard.class

```
public class SDcard extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.missing_sd);
      //  Button inserted_card = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_insert);
       // inserted_card.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //public void onClick(View v) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Card Inserted!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //}
        //});

    }
}
```

> i commented onclick part to make sure it is not working!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, for example:

```
//in onCreate
if (somecondition) {
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
}
else {
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
}
```

But if you provide different functionality in such cases, wouldn't it be better to start different activities based on the condition?

For example:

```
//in onCreate
if (somecondition) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
else {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: ok that way also i can. now in if(level < 10), i open an activity else another then in this there wont be setContentView() ??? right???

Comment: Didn't under stand your comment, may you rephrase?

Comment: i'll give an example. consider the below format. will this work??? isSDCard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);                                                              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if( isSDCard )
        {
         Intent batIntent = new Intent(this,SDcard.class);
         startActivity(batIntent);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: This may cause you a problem, because you call setContentView after another activity has started.

Comment: yeah tried but adding the setcontentview() inside else also, its not working.

Comment: thanks :) but when i add the intent instead of setcontentview() my app force closes....

Comment: i have removed and have added in my own question

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that

```
   if (level < 10) {
        // navigate or finish();
    }else{
       // Do nothing
    }
```

I hope this is, what you asking..

Comment: can i open an activity inside the if statement. cause there are touch events to activate the intent????

Comment: yes you can do like this     setContentView(R.layout.map);
        // code for battery level 
        (--)
  if(level < 10 ){
   finish();
  }else{
   Intent intent = new Intent(OfflineMapActivity.this, RatingActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
  }